# Find the volume bound by the curve $\gamma(t) = (e^{\sin(t)}\cos(t),e^{\cos(t)}\sin(t))$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, bessel-functions

Find the volume bound by the curve $\gamma(t) = (e^{\sin(t)}\cos(t),e^{\cos(t)}\sin(t))$

I've tried computing directly with $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R r \, dr \, d\theta$ where $R = \sqrt{(e^{\sin(t)}\cos(t))^2+(e^{\cos(t)}\sin(t))^2}$ but this seems unfruitful.

I've also tried considering the path as a line integral over the vector field $F=(-y,x)$, which gives us the area by Green's theorem. Here's why...

\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma F \cdot dr = \int_\gamma -y\,dx+x\,dy = \iint\limits_\Omega dA = \mathrm{Area}(\Omega)
\end{equation}

Where $\Omega$ is the region bound by the curve. But this attempt also seems unfruitful. To be honest I'm not sure if this is even possible without numerical methods. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Among other things, I changed \underset{\Omega}{\int \int} to \iint\limits_\Omega (with two consecutive "i"s).  Thus instead of $\displaystyle\underset{\Omega}{\int \int}$ we see $\displaystyle\iint\limits_\Omega$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: By computing $\gamma\wedge\gamma'$ I got $$\pi  \left(2 \text{Hypergeometric0F1Regularized}\left[1,\frac{1}{2}\right]-\frac{3}{2} \text{Hypergeometric0F1Regularized}\left[2,\frac{1}{2}\right]\right).$$

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with what you just wrote. Hypergeometric 0F1 Regularized !?!

Comment: Just a comment that your first approach can't work, because the parametric form is not of the form $(x,y)=R(\theta)(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

Comment: @user152558: as shown below, the area depends on certain values of Bessel functions, hence it does not have a nice closed expression, but can be computed through a really fast converging series.

Answer (score 2):

$$\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))=\left(e^{\sin t}\cos t,\,e^{\cos t}\sin t\right)$$
is a closed simple curve around the origin, counter-clockwise oriented. The enclosed area is given by:
$$ A = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(xy'-yx'\right)\,dt = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos t+\sin t}\left(4-\cos t-\sin t+\cos(3t)-\sin(3t)\right)\,dt $$
or, by setting $t=x+\frac{\pi}{4}$,
$$ A = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\sqrt{2}\cos x}\left(4-\sqrt{2}\cos x-\sqrt{2}\cos(3x)\right)\,dx.\tag{1} $$
Since for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\alpha\cos x}\cos(nx)\,dx = 2\pi\cdot I_{n}(\alpha)\tag{2}$$
by the integral definition of the [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), it follows that:
$$ A = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}\left(4\, I_0(\sqrt{2})-\sqrt{2}\, I_1(\sqrt{2})-\sqrt{2}\, I_3(\sqrt{2})\right)}=\color{blue}{3.84713365\ldots}.\tag{3} $$
The area has so a fast-converging series representation given by:
$$ A = \color{purple}{\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^m\,m!^2}\left(4-\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{1}{2(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)}\right)}.\tag{4}$$